# Run multiple commands in one line fails when using "\x" with PSQL (POSTGRES)

Tags: postgresql, psql, kubectl

I'm trying to run the following queries in one line:

```
\x
select * from pg_stat_statements order by max_exec_time desc limit 10;
```

As follows:

```
kubectl -n MYNAMESPACEXXX exec -ti MYPGPOD-K8SXXX -- psql -d MY-DB -U postgres -c '\x select * from pg_stat_statements order by max_exec_time desc limit 10;'
```

But I get

```
unrecognized value "select" for "expanded"
Available values are: on, off, auto.
command terminated with exit code 1
```

How can we combine both `\x` and the SQL query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to use the `-c` option several times:

```sh
psql -c '\x' -c 'SELECT ...'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the `expanded` mode from the commandline:

---

```
  kubectl -n MYNAMESPACEXXX exec -ti MYPGPOD-K8SXXX -- psql -d MY-DB -U postgres --expanded -c 'select * from pg_stat_statements order by max_exec_time desc limit 10;'
```